# Dynamic text component data through JSON on A-Scene?

Tags: aframe

Hi everyone how  to do it if so can you share demos or examples ...

How to do it ....

I tried many was using the text components but not able to find an exact way to do it ...

Comment: You need to provide more information on what you are trying to do with a code snippet.

Comment: @ngokevin I am trying to display text data which keeps updating  like I have done in Ajax in normal HTML ...

Answer (score 0):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/guides/using-javascript-and-dom-apis.html

`el.setAttribute('text', {text: 'Hello, World!'})`

`el.setAttribute('bmfont-text', {text: 'Hello, World!'})`